# Two interfaces on same machine with same subnet

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wired-networking

I would like to maintain just a single subnet (`192.168.2.x/24`) for static-IP-assigned client devices of a certain class on a server. ASCII art of the network topology:

```
-------------------
Ubuntu Server      |       -----------------------------
192.168.2.1 : eth0 | <--> | eth0: 192.168.2.101: client1 |
                   |       ------------------------------
                   |       ------------------------------
192.168.2.2 : eth1 | <--> | eth0: 192.168.2.102: client2 |
-------------------        ------------------------------
```

Note there is NO other hardware (e.g. no switches). Just one server and two client devices.

**Is it rational to have two Ethernet interfaces have the same subnet on the same machine?** I'm hoping to avoid the need to put in a small switch between the server and the client devices just to keep the subnet clean.

Comment: Are the clients directly connected to the two ethernet ports or are all 4 ports connected to the same switch or hub? In the first case you might need a specific routing table to let the server know which interface must be used for which client. In the second case the server might not use the interfaces in the way you want.

Comment: I think it's perfectly fine to put two IPs and/or NICs on the same server with the same subnet to have multiple inbound and outbound paths for network traffic. If you are using DNS to round robin, etc. the IP addresses on the server or hard coding client pointers for half the clients to connect to one and the other half to the other using IP or DNS name is just fine. If you want to control which clients send to which, or use some DNS round robin, etc. mechanism it should all work and be just fine. You know your environments and requirements best though ultimately. How complex do you need tho?

Comment: @Bodo no switch or hub. Just a 4-port NIC on the Ubuntu server and two other client devices that have no connection to one another.

Comment: @Vomit IT - Chunky Mess Style, everything is statically assigned in this case.

Comment: I think it will be just fine if everything is statically assigned. You will use cross over cables for the Ethernet connections between devices without using a switch though, but all should work just as you expect. Since you are statically assigning everything, should make it even more solid I would think. I'd set it up and test basic ping, etc. at each step before you move onto the next step.  Configs are static for IPs, client config pointers to Ubunutu server IPs, and the cross over cables connecting device NIC to device NIC are static too, so you should be just fine.

Comment: I have not ever done this before though with this type of setup, but the way I learn is to try and troubleshoot. I'd be interested in what you determine as you dig into this and any issues that pop up along the way. It might take some routing table adjustments perhaps as indicated in the first comment. Not sure if playing with subnet mask, default gateway, etc. in each nic IPv4 config could make it work somehow too.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add all information/clarification to the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you do this as pictured, it will **not** be the same subnet: it will be two subnets that happen to be identically numbered, but are completely isolated from each other.

Usually when that's done, packets from the server will always end up being routed through *one* interface (i.e. routing is done for the entire /24 as a unit, not for individual hosts), e.g. if the server prioritizes the route via eth0, then hosts on eth0 will be able to communicate with the server but hosts on eth1 will never receive any response, as the preferred route to 192.168.2.102 goes via eth0. Clients on different interfaces won't be able to reach each other at all.

A switch does not make an Ethernet subnet "not clean" – a switch is the *normal* way of creating Ethernet subnets with more than 2 devices. (For example, with home routers that have the typical four LAN ports in a single subnet, there is indeed an internal 'switch' linking those ports together, so that the router's CPU only sees it as a single interface.)

But your server does not have that – all it has is two independent Ethernet interfaces. So in order to create a single subnet like home routers do, but without buying an external Ethernet switch, you would need to enable software-based Ethernet bridging instead. (It behaves the same way a switch would, only the server's CPU does all the work.)

(On Linux you do this by creating a 'bridge' interface using `ip link add br0 type bridge`, moving both eth0 and eth1 into the bridge using `ip link set eth0 master br0`, and assigning an IP address from the subnet to br0 and only to br0.)

Without being bridged, however, each interface needs to be on a separate subnet for things to work properly. They would still belong to one *network,* i.e. the server could act as a router and clients in different subnets could communicate.

(It is also possible to sort-of *emulate* a single subnet between several separate interfaces, but then the server needs to know routes for each individual host, as well as provide Proxy-ARP to allow hosts talk across interfaces, and that's just a real mess.)